# Calculate a field in real time ExtJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs, event-handling

I have a completion date field and an expiration date field in my ExtJS form. When a user selects a completion date, I want the expiration date to be automatically filled after the completion date is selected.

Here is what I have so far:

```
        var completionDate = {
                fieldLabel: 'Completion Date',
                xtype: 'datefield',
                submitFormat: 'time',
                name: 'trainingCompletion',
                labelAlign: 'right',
                labelWidth: 150,
                readOnly: false,
                readOnlyCls: 'readOnlyFields',
                listeners: {
                    select: function (dateField, newValue, oldValue){ 
                        expirationDate.oldValue = newValue;
                    }
                },

        };
        var expirationDate = {
                fieldLabel: 'Expiration Date',
                xtype: 'datefield',
                submitFormat: 'time',
                name: 'trainingExpiration',
                labelAlign: 'right',
                labelWidth: 150,
                readOnly: true,
                readOnlyCls: 'iamis_readOnlyFields'
        };
```

The function should then add 15 months to the `completionDate`but I want to get it to update first

Code for declaring `trainingCompletion` and `trainingExpiration`

```
{name: 'trainingCompletion', type: 'date', dateReadFormat: 'time', dateWriteFormat: 'm/d/Y', useNull: true},
{name: 'trainingExpiration', type: 'date', dateReadFormat: 'time', dateWriteFormat: 'm/d/Y', useNull: true},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The provided code looks very incomplete.

When declaring listeners you should pay attention to the scope where the listener will be executed. Supposing these 2 datefields are on a form, you should define the listener's scope to guarantee that you will have the right reference to the expiration field.

I do something similar to you in my code, so i will share a code that do this in my programming style, but you can adapt it to your coding style.

```
Ext.define("My.form.Task", {
    extend: "Ext.form.Panel",
    alias: "widget.mytaskform",
    buttonAlign: "left",
    defaults: {
        anchor: '100%',
        margin: '10px 0px 0px 0px',
        labelAlign: 'left',
        labelWidth: 125
    },
    initComponent: function() {
        this.items = [{
                fieldLabel: 'Completion Date',
                xtype: 'datefield',
                submitFormat: 'time',
                name: 'trainingCompletion',
                labelAlign: 'right',
                labelWidth: 150,
                readOnly: false,
                readOnlyCls: 'readOnlyFields',
                listeners: {
                    select: {
                        scope: this,
                        fn: function (dateField, newValue, oldValue){
                            var expirationField = this.down("[name=trainingExpiration]");
                            // You need to add the desired months to the date
                            // before setting it to the expirationField.
                            expirationField.setValue(newValue);
                        }
                    }
                },

        },{
                fieldLabel: 'Expiration Date',
                xtype: 'datefield',
                submitFormat: 'time',
                name: 'trainingExpiration',
                labelAlign: 'right',
                labelWidth: 150,
                readOnly: true,
                readOnlyCls: 'iamis_readOnlyFields'
        }];
        this.callParent(arguments);
    },
    // form remaining code...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks wrong:

```
expirationDate.oldValue = newValue
```

Instead you should be using the proper setValue() method on the datefield

```
expirationDate.setValue(newValue);
```

Comment: I'm getting this error in Firebug                                                       TypeError: trainingExpiration.setValue is not a function

Comment: Umm ok, so how are you defining the trainingExpiration variable? It doesn't look like you have posted your entire code either.

Comment: trainingExpiration defined as a user attribute in a separate object, the 'name' in expirationDate is pointing to said attribute

Comment: I've added that to the post

Comment: Ok so it looks like you have added model definitions there for a store? The name config of the datefield does not map to a named column in a model definition, its used for something else - http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Date-cfg-name